# Python doctest does not run on files named as signal.py

Tags: python, doctest

## Problem

I'm using python 3.6.6 on Fedora 28. I have a project structure as follows :

```
test/__init__.py
test/signal.py
test/notsignal.py
```

If I run `$ python3 -m doctest -v test/signal.py`
I get:

```
10 items had no tests:
    signal
    signal.Handlers
    signal.ItimerError
    signal.Sigmasks
    signal.Signals
    signal._enum_to_int
    signal._int_to_enum
    signal.struct_siginfo
    signal.struct_siginfo.__reduce__
    signal.struct_siginfo.__repr__
0 tests in 10 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

which, to me, clearly shows that `doctest` is trying to run on the built-in `signal` module.  By renaming the file I was able to run `docset`. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

## To reproduce

You may use the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p test
touch test/__init__.py
echo -e ""'"'""'"'""'"'"\n>>> _ = print(f'Doctest at {__name__} was run.')\n"'"'""'"'""'"'"" > test/signal.py
cp test/signal.py test/notsignal.py
python3 -m doctest -v test/signal.py
python3 -m doctest -v test/notsignal.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [doctest source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f85b826b527e240551613aeec3118a5469e3a33/Lib/doctest.py#L2769), you can see that doctest tries to import the modules that you pass to it.

It's very likely that the standard library's signal module has already been imported:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;import doctest;print("signal" in sys.modules)'
True
```

When doctest tries the import the Python interpreter finds that there is already a module named "signal" in `sys.modules` and returns that rather than your signal module.

Perhaps this is a bug - maybe doctest could be smarter about how it imports - but in practice I think the best course of action is to rename your module. In general, having modules with the same names as standard library modules almost always causes problems.

Comment: I see, thank you!  I think this can be considered a bug, since it's an unexpected behavior that is not documented.